# How to set a timer server-wide

Tags: java, timer, bukkit

The tile does not describe it properly so im going to try and describe it here:

I have a bukkit plugin, its a minigame.

It must have some code run for 10 minutes and then run another code until that game is finished

I currently have this:
Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

```
            public void run() {

                // code for 10 minutes

            }

        }, 600000);
```

//code for after

Yet, this is only affects a single player and not that world.
So if one player joins he will wait 10 minutes and then run the otherpart of the code and so on, when the purpose is the 10 minutes start couting on their own, even if there is no player.
Thanks

Comment: Could you specify problem more ? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timer_schedule_period.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably caused because your code is all triggered by an event?
Meaning it will only ever effect the player that triggered that event.

Instead you need a generic plugin that does not trigger on events (except for login), but instead it uses a timer and then grabs a list of all players and runs your code on each/all of them. Then after 10min it will exit to your other code and run that for the rest of the time.

Edit: rough example:

```
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

    public final class {$PluginName} extends JavaPlugin {
        @Override
        public void onEnable() { //This should proberbly be done onCommand rather than onEnable
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (some condition....){
                        //load list of players
                        //now iterate through player list and do your code
                        //check if 10min has passed:
                        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) > 600000){
                            //now break the loop and run your other code for the rest of the minigame
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //code for the rest of the minigame
                    while (true){
                        //load list of players
                        //now iterate through player list and do your code for the rest of the time
                    }
                }
           }); 
           thread.start();               
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah. I eventually figured this out on my own, I guess I was being dumb. Now I have another slight problem. How do I start a diferent file ( gamestart.class ) from the main file? Clearifiyng: I want to start that code you gave me, present on a diferent file, from the main file. Thanks!

Comment: @sorifiendsoz forgot to id you

Comment: @HiperBolt It really depends what sort of class gamestart is. Does it extend a thread? Or is it just a normal class? Else you can just use this from your normal class `gamestart.mymethod();`, and then in your gamestart class you can run whatever code you want in the mymethod method. However before doing anything I highly recommend you get a better grasp on Java by running through these tutorials on working with classes and objects: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: Thanks I guess this will work. Its my first time working with java; I am experienced with Python, Bash and Lua though, so its not being very hard